# Continuous production of amber by trees in one location

Tags: fossils, evolution, amber

In which well known amber location did trees produce amber for the longest continuous period of time, roughly how long was it, and was it long enough to see signs of evolution at work in any of the species trapped in the amber?

Comment: related to this question https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut6vosxD_lM